# Spinning a diamond shape in css

Tags: css

I have a diamond-shaped div made by transforming the square.

```
.dn-diamond {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #000;
  /* Rotate */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  margin: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Is there any way I could spin it around its own axis?
I was trying to do this:

```
.dn-diamond:hover {
    animation: spin 3s infinite linear;
}
@keyframes spin {
    from { transform: rotateY(0deg); }
    to { transform: rotateY(360deg); }
}
```

It does what I want to do, but it changes the diamond to the square.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/akshay7/jfwzkp22/ ?

Answer (score 1):

Just add `rotate(-45deg)` to your spin animation:

```css
.dn-diamond {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  margin: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dn-diamond:hover {
  animation: spin 3s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes spin {
  from { 
    transform: rotateY(0deg) rotate(-45deg); 
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateY(360deg) rotate(-45deg); 
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="dn-diamond">
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `transform` in both, this fails. The easiest way to solve this is to wrap the diamond in a div, and have that div spin instead.

```
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='dn-diamond'></div>
</div>
```

Then in CSS:

```
.wrapper:hover {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  animation: spin 3s infinite linear;
}
```

Comment: problem with this is the diamond is does't look spinning it goes only side by side